# g++ linker error “undefined reference to "Class::function"”

Tags: linker, makefile, g++

I'm using the makefile to compile my C++ project in a linux IDE.
The makefile is as follows:

```
#-------------------------------
SRCDIR=src
ICDDIR=include
TESTDIR=test

CC=g++ 
OBJS = main.o Complex.o TestComplex.o
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS = -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)

#-------------------------------
test : $(OBJS)
    $(CC)   $(LFLAGS)   $(OBJS) -o  output  -I  $(ICDDIR)

main.o : $(SRCDIR)/main.cpp 
    $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   $(SRCDIR)/main.cpp  -I  $(ICDDIR)

Complex.o : $(SRCDIR)/Complex.cpp $(ICDDIR)/Complex.h
    $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   $(SRCDIR)/Complex.cpp -I    $(ICDDIR)

TestComplex.o : $(TESTDIR)/TestComplex.cpp $(ICDDIR)/TestComplex.h $(ICDDIR)/Complex.h 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(TESTDIR)/TestComplex.cpp -I   $(ICDDIR)
```

And the terrible error message:
make

```
g++     -Wall -c -g     src/main.cpp    -I      include
g++     -Wall -c -g     src/Complex.cpp -I      include
g++  -Wall -c -g test/TestComplex.cpp -I        include
g++     -Wall -g        main.o Complex.o TestComplex.o  -o      output  -I     i
nclude
main.o: In function `main':
proj1/src/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to
 `Complex::Complex()'
proj1/src/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to
 `Complex::Complex()'
proj1/src/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to
 `Complex::Complex(double, double)'
proj1/src/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to
 `Complex::Complex(double, double)'
TestComplex.o: In function `TestComplex::TestComplex()':
proj1/test/TestComplex.cpp:8: undefined refer
ence to `Complex::Complex()'
TestComplex.o: In function `TestComplex::compute(Complex, Complex)':
proj1/test/TestComplex.cpp:34: undefined refe
rence to `operator+(Complex const&, Complex const&)'
proj1/test/TestComplex.cpp:37: undefined refe
rence to `operator-(Complex const&, Complex const&)'
proj1/test/TestComplex.cpp:40: undefined refe
rence to `operator*(Complex const&, Complex const&)'
proj1/test/TestComplex.cpp:43: undefined refe
rence to `operator/(Complex const&, Complex const&)'
proj1/test/TestComplex.cpp:46: undefined refe
rence to `operator==(Complex const&, Complex const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The structure of my project:

```
src/
    Complex.cpp
    main.cpp
include/
    Complex.h
    TeseComplex.h
test/
    TestComplex.cpp
Makefile
```

All my header files and sources files are implemented correctly.
I guess this is a linker problem, but I do link all .o together. 
I have no idea what's going wrong,I hope someone could help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

> All my header files and sources files are implemented correctly.

No, they are not.

> I guess this is a linker problem,

Your guess is incorrect.

Unfortunately, you have not provided sufficient info to help you further. Showing the `include/Complex.h` and `src/Complex.cpp` will likely help.